# Question about regression and deriving omitted variables

Tags: regression, endogeneity, omitted-variable-bias

usually when I see derivations of ommited variable bias, I see something of the sort:
from y=xb + $\eta$, and looking at the for formula for the slope estimate:

1. $cov(x,y)$$/var(x)$
2. $cov(x,xb+\eta )$$/var(x)$=
3. b + $cov(x,\eta)$$/var(x)$

my question is, how does intuitively step 2 make sense? plugging in y in to the covariance formula? Is it that we are taking y=xb + $\eta$ literally of how Y is being generated, and so any y we see in the population is theoretically equivalent to  xb + $\eta$?

Comment: I don't get your question, because the gist of it reads, "assuming $y=xb+\eta,$ why is it valid to substitute $xb+\eta$ for $y$ in a covariance calculation?"  There seems to be nothing to say.  What am I missing?

Comment: I think I should have worded 'assuming' as part of the question- just meant its usually stated in that way, so is that saying that y literally equal to xb +$\eta$?

Comment: Equations are meant pretty literally, so yes.

Comment: Wikipedia shows the derivation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omitted-variable_bias#Detailed_analysis).

Comment: This appears to be the same thing as [regression dilution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_dilution). A statistician might say regression dilution but may not know the econometric term, omitted variable bias. It boils down to the difference between bivariate regression like Deming regression, and univariate regression minimizing the error in $y$ alone. The first estimates the replacement line in an assay, and the latter a minimum error in $y$-alone. Most people have never heard of it.